# How to move UITabBar button down

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have a custom tab bar and each buttonitem is a custom button. However the top is at the very edge. Is there anyway I can push this down?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out

```
[self setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0)];
```

(This is placed in a UITabBarItem subclass)